# my app is working on testFlight but not on my review app

Tags: ios, crash, applescript

Impossible to find the problem of my crash because the app works fine on my testFlight me if also works fine on my Emulator.

When i received the message from Apple and I go to my Organizer and reports> crashes, I have this

[image]

when I click on that I found the crashlog, but I don't understand what it means. I have already checked all my code but i change juste small front thing compared to the other version

```
Incident Identifier: AC1702C1-5B92-49D3-A4B5-F9599CFE597D
Hardware Model:      iPhone9,3
Process:             Klaaap [423]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/48F2CC89-2889-4E4B-BE29-901FBB81E3DF/Klaaap.app/Klaaap
Identifier:          .com.YouKlaaap.KlaaapIos
Version:             3.23 (3.23)
AppStoreTools:       12D4d
AppVariant:          1:iPhone9,3:14
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           .com.YouKlaaap.KlaaapIos [579]


Date/Time:           2021-04-20 09:58:45.9040 +0200
Launch Time:         2021-04-20 09:58:45.5246 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.4.2 (18D70)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    5.01.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18b9419d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 216 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19fcc4b54 objc_exception_throw + 56 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   Klaaap                          0x100ee080c RCTFatal + 668 (RCTAssert.m:145)
3   Klaaap                          0x100ef64f0 __28-[RCTCxxBridge handleError:]_block_invoke + 712 (RCTCxxBridge.mm:981)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x18b579298 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1454)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x18b57a280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:559)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x18b52905c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 896 (inline_internal.h:2548)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x18b8c15e0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1790)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x18b8bba88 __CFRunLoopRun + 2480 (CFRunLoop.c:3118)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x18b8baba0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
10  GraphicsServices                0x1a2620598 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2259)
11  UIKitCore                       0x18e1ac2f4 -[UIApplication _run] + 1052 (UIApplication.m:3253)
12  UIKitCore                       0x18e1b1874 UIApplicationMain + 164 (UIApplication.m:4707)
13  Klaaap                          0x100e02858 main + 80 (main.m:7)
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x18b599568 start + 4

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b787d84c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d41649e8 pthread_kill + 212 (pthread.c:1392)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019463c8f4 abort + 100 (abort.c:110)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019fdc0cc8 abort_message + 128 (abort_message.cpp:76)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019fdb2ca0 demangling_terminate_handler() + 296 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:67)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019fcc4e04 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019fdc0154 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000019fdc00ec std::terminate() + 44 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b57a294 _dispatch_client_callout + 36 (object.m:562)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b52905c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 896 (inline_internal.h:2548)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b8c15e0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12 (CFRunLoop.c:1790)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b8bba88 __CFRunLoopRun + 2480 (CFRunLoop.c:3118)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b8baba0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
13  GraphicsServices                0x00000001a2620598 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2259)
14  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e1ac2f4 -[UIApplication _run] + 1052 (UIApplication.m:3253)
15  UIKitCore                       0x000000018e1b1874 UIApplicationMain + 164 (UIApplication.m:4707)
16  Klaaap                          0x0000000100e02858 main + 80 (main.m:7)
17  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018b599568 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d416886c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d416886c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   Klaaap                          0x0000000100e464d4 0x100dfc000 + 304340
1   Klaaap                          0x0000000100ea21e4 __38+[FBLPromise(DoAdditions) onQueue:do:]_block_invoke + 40 (FBLPromise+Do.m:33)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b579298 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24 (init.c:1454)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b57a280 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:559)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b52c1a8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 996 (inline_internal.h:2534)
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b52c704 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 124 (queue.c:6777)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4165568 _pthread_wqthread + 212 (pthread.c:2223)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4168874 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b785a644 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7859a48 mach_msg + 72 (mach_msg.c:103)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b8c10fc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 376 (CFRunLoop.c:2641)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b8bb570 __CFRunLoopRun + 1176 (CFRunLoop.c:2974)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018b8baba0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
5   Foundation                      0x000000018cada7f8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 228 (NSRunLoop.m:374)
6   Foundation                      0x000000018cada6d8 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 88 (NSRunLoop.m:421)
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000018e258054 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 504 (UIEventFetcher.m:838)
8   Foundation                      0x000000018cc374bc __NSThread__start__ + 848 (NSThread.m:724)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4163c9c _pthread_start + 288 (pthread.c:881)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4168880 thread_start + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d416886c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d416886c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d416886c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d416886c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9 name:
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b787d61c __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d415d45c _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 1180 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000019fd60ea4 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::r... + 96 (__threading_support:396)
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001954c5918 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop() + 656 (__mutex_base:0)
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001954c5198 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadEntryPoint(bmalloc::Scavenger*) + 12 (Scavenger.cpp:395)
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001954c68c0 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::Scavenger*), bmalloc::Scaveng... + 44 (type_traits:3545)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4163c9c _pthread_start + 288 (pthread.c:881)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001d4168880 thread_start + 8

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000019fdc3f31   x5: 0x000000016f0025a0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000033
    x8: 0x0000000101547880   x9: 0x0b1b39c848a120ca  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x00000001d6896c4a  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000010  x15: 0x0000000000000009
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000407  x21: 0x0000000101547960  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000000000114  x25: 0x0000000283764f00  x26: 0x0000000101547960  x27: 0x00000000000020ff
   x28: 0x0000000002ffffff   fp: 0x000000016f002500   lr: 0x00000001d41649e8
    sp: 0x000000016f0024e0   pc: 0x00000001b787d84c cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault



The problem seems to come from there : 


 // Expected resulting exception information:
      // name: RCTFatalException: <underlying error description>
      // reason: <underlying error description plus JS stack trace, truncated to 175 characters>
      // userInfo: <underlying error userinfo, plus untruncated description plus JS stack trace>
      @throw [[NSException alloc] initWithName:name reason:message userInfo:userInfo]; **Last Exception Backtrace (0)**
#if DEBUG
    } @catch (NSException *e) {
    }
#endif
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading your question correctly - not being critical, but your English is pretty rough to understand. Are you saying that you have a crash log you downloaded? Have you tried opening it in your Xcode project (top right button in Organizer)? It should point you to the line of code causing the crash.

Comment: sorry for that .. I add the picture of my error. It's on a swift language and i'm not very confortable with it

Comment: You have tagged AppleScript, but I suspect that you are using React Native, since that is what is throwing an exception after initialisation. Do you get any othe exception message that says what went wrong with react ?